# How to access FD_SETSIZE in Ruby? spawn cpp (??)

Tags: ruby, io, stream, posix, file-descriptor

While reading up about IO in Ruby, moreover refreshing my own albeit limited knowledge about I/O in generally POSIX-friendly libc environments, I found a question here at Stack Overflow: [poll() in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726352/poll-in-ruby) such that raises the question that was the object of research.

The responses had mentioned the availability of a `select` method in Ruby. However, it also raised a concern about using `select` under certain conditions on some operating systems - including Linux - e.g when there may be 1024 or more file descriptors open in the Ruby process.

In some of the responses to the question, [poll() in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726352/poll-in-ruby), it was suggested that if `select` was called in such an environment, that it could result in memory corruption in the application. While the concern might not be represented as being of such severity, in other documentation, and there may be a way to portably avoid calling `select` in such circumstances - as later reading has indicated - perhaps the question remains as to how to address this portably, for Ruby's `select`.

Reading more about it, I noticed that the "BUGS" section of the [select(2) manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html), on Linux, provides what may represent an expansive discussion of the issue. The text mentions a constant, `FD_SETSIZE` as apparently representing the exclusive upper limit on the number of file descriptors that can be open at the time when `select` is called, such that `select` might be expected to perform normally then (roughly paraphrased).

Quoting the **select(2)** manual page:

```
   POSIX allows an implementation to define an upper limit,
   advertised via the constant FD_SETSIZE, on the range of file
   descriptors that can be specified in a file descriptor set.  The
   Linux kernel imposes no fixed limit, but the glibc implementation
   makes fd_set a fixed-size type, with FD_SETSIZE defined as 1024,
   and the FD_*() macros operating according to that limit.  To
   monitor file descriptors greater than 1023, use poll(2) or
   epoll(7) instead.

   The implementation of the fd_set arguments as value-result
   arguments is a design error that is avoided in poll(2) and
   epoll(7).

   According to POSIX, select() should check all specified file
   descriptors in the three file descriptor sets, up to the limit
   nfds-1.  However, the current implementation ignores any file
   descriptor in these sets that is greater than the maximum file
   descriptor number that the process currently has open.  According
   to POSIX, any such file descriptor that is specified in one of
   the sets should result in the error EBADF.
```

Towards making use of this in Ruby, albeit in what may be a guess of an approach: What might be the best way to determine `FD_SETSIZE` for the Ruby environment?

If it was available as a constant, this assumes that the value of that constant could be used in a conditional test before calling 'select' on any open file descriptor. The Ruby program might then raise an exception internally, before calling `select` on any file descriptor equal to or greater than the value of `FD_SETSIZE` for the instance, at least for generally POSIX-friendly operating systems?

If there's no cleaner way to approach this, maybe it could be worked into the distribution tooling for a project, such as to determine that constant's value for the target architecture then to store it along with any other application constants? I'm guessing a `cpp` could be used for this - whether from GCC, LLVM, or any other toolchain - perhaps in some ways similar to [sb-grovel](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#sb_002dgrovel).

Maybe there's some other way to approach this, and portably so? Perhaps there's already a constant for it, somewhere in Ruby?

Maybe there's already some checking about it, in the Ruby source code? I suppose it's time to look for that GitHub repository now....

Comment: Why not try and see if you can find a `poll` or `epoll` implementation instead? Checking FD_SETSIZE will most likely require a compiler anyway. What exactly is it you want to achieve in the end? Why are you asking this question? If the purpose is to build an app with > 1024 sockets, then would it not be easier to look for an `(e)poll` implementation (gem)?

Comment: I'd asked the question in the interest of portability, hoping it may've been addressed in some meaningful way. At the question I'd located, addressing the availability of a poll in ruby, there was one response suggesting that at least one poll-like interface was using select, internally. Even if using a compiler hack at build time, I'd like to limit a certain application's runtime dependencies to the ruby standard library, if possible

Answer (score 0):

Ruby does not export FD_SETSIZE in any way, so the only way to check the size is to use a compiler.

Instead of [building your own extension](https://riptutorial.com/ruby/example/17669/your-first-extension), the least hassle-free way may be to use [RubyInline](https://www.zenspider.com/projects/rubyinline.html), which makes the check very simple:

```
gem install RubyInline
```

Then:

```
require 'inline'

class FdTest
  inline do |builder|
    builder.c "
      long fd_setsize(void) {
        return FD_SETSIZE;
      }"
  end
end

puts FdTest.new.fd_setsize

=> 1024
```

This is even semi-portable to Windows, provided you are running under WSL, Cygwin, MinGW, or something similar. Might even work under Visual Studio, provided it is installed with C-support.

Building it as an extension might be another solution to ensure better compatibility, which you can then ship with precompiled binaries for your required platforms.

It all depends on how much trouble you are willing to go through in order to extract this information on all possible platforms, since there really does not exist a fully platform independent solution to something like this.